# Is there a good way of telling typescript all array elements exist in a Map?

Tags: typescript, strictnullchecks

Let's say I'm creating a Map from an array of objects with ids as keys, then accessing the map from a different array that has the same ids:

```
const arr1 = [
  {id: 'a', firstName: 'Jeff'},
  {id: 'b', firstName: 'John'},
  {id: 'c', firstName: 'Jeremy'}
];

const map1 = new Map(arr1.map(element => [element.id, element]));

const arr2 = [
  {id: 'b', lastName: 'Johnson'},
  {id: 'c', lastName: 'Jackson'},
  {id: 'd', lastName: 'Jenkins'}
];

const arr2InMap1 = arr2.filter(element => map1.has(element.id));
arr2InMap1.forEach(element => console.log(`${map1.get(element.id).firstName} ${element.lastName}`));
```

If I have "strictNullChecks": true, then the final line would throw an "Object is possibly 'undefined'" error, even though it can never be undefined.
Is there a way of telling typescript that the elements in the array exist in the map?

I know I can use the '!' operator, or create a function that only returns T instead of T | undefined to replace Map.get, but is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: This is because `map.get` always returns `T | undefined`. SInce `Map` is mutable data structure, it is always safer to check if it is `undefined` or not

Comment: You can use optional chaining so that typescript stops throwing object is possibly undefined error. Although that would mean that undefined also can be logged. 

`map1.get(element.id).firstName` would become `map1.get(element.id)?.firstName`

Comment: This is just a bare bones example, in my code this pattern repeats a lot. I could use conditional chaining, but then I would have to add it to everything that uses the result, which I would rather not do. Also the thing is it can never be undefined because I filter out all values that would return undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is the signature for `Map.get`. If this is bothersome, a plain object might work better for your case:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=97#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQRhgXhgbQFAxgbwEsATALhgHI4KAaGAM0IWgDk4BbAU3IoClP69CgF8auAiR4AjWgyasO3SrxAALMCLF4iZSsFmNmUNlx78EndgE8R2ALoBubNlCRYiBACZ0WcTumyADZwCqbKapDgmn6SekEhxopmcMAA1hBRojG6FMTxoUp8nGCphJC2js6u0DAgUgBWqBgeyAB0FsQArsCcABTivXX1dABucIGdnACU6AB8MIMNmGMTnK0kdj4rkzMAZLu1DVoEwvAQMABKnKAIxAA80AhlAOZ0UFYADpwg9PBIyJgwJ12FJOAg7LMxFMnC5wDUPJ4AJJgACycA+TT+XlajECUDBvU4gUsxVgaHmRJJYCg62IMDKh0a0OwCORaIxOJACAAoilVITiVxqXMYNUQMTWoEQM9egADAAk+CGAMpQppGxx8kSXFOitVpMlCRMnGEsqm0KAA)

```ts
const obj1 = arr1.reduce(
  (obj, value) => (obj[value.id] = value) && obj,
  {} as Record<string, typeof arr1[number]>,
);

const arr2InMap1 = arr2.filter(element => element.id in obj1);
arr2InMap1.forEach(element => console.log(`${obj1[element.id].firstName} ${element.lastName}`));
```

Comment: Then I run into warnings about Generic Object Injection Sink, which I also would like to avoid.

Comment: @EyalBenari I've never seen that before. Quick research pointed me to [this doc](https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security/blob/master/docs/the-dangers-of-square-bracket-notation.md) which says that it appears when you don't sanitize user input and then use it to index. In any case, it's not TypeScript-related.

Comment: I use eslint security plugin and it hates using square bracket notation with a variable that isn't a static string. It's the main reason I switched to Maps in the first place, to avoid having to sanitize and ignore the warnings.